# How to show $x^4 - 1296 = (x^3-6x^2+36x-216)(x+6)$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How to get this result: $x^4-1296 = (x^3-6x^2+36x-216)(x+6)$?

It is part of a question about finding limits at [mooculus](https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/limitCompute).

Comment: Dividing $x^4-1296$ by $x+6$?

Comment: This is much easier if you recognise $1296$ as being $6^4$ straight away, but if not it factorises very quickly.

Comment: In general, you should remember that differences of $n$-th powers are factorizable, and sums of $m$-th powers are when $m$ is odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints: $1296=(-6)^4$ and $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$.

Comment: Then $x^4-6^4=(x-6)(x^3+6x^2+36x+216)$, great! The formula works! Is there any tips for exchange $x-6$ by $x+6$ in the expression?

Comment: @Lourenco My tip was actually suggesting to make $a=x$ and $b=-6$. So $a-b=x+6$.

Comment: Very good! Thank you!

Comment: @Lourenco You're welcome. This factorization of $a^n-b^n$,  in particular $r^n-1$ gets used all the time. For instance, you'll see it again when you meet geometric sums and geometric series.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a harder and similar way, but it still makes sense if you don't have what Julien said memorized.

$$x^4 - 1296 = x^4 - 6^4 \Rightarrow x^4 = 6^4$$Now two roots that seem obvious are $6$ and $-6$. But $x^4 =  x^4 \cdot 1 = x^4 \cdot i^4 = (xi)^4$. So two more roots are $6i$ and $-6i$.

Hence, the factorization is $$\begin{aligned}&(x - 6)(x + 6)(x+6i)(x - 6i) \\  =& (x-6)(x+6)(x^2+36) \\ =& (x+6)(x^3 - 6x^2 +36x-216)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Note that the factorization is easily derivable by the Factor Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It really helps! I just accepted julien responses because it is generic.

Answer (score 4):

A bit more roundabout way:

$x^4 - 1296 \ $ is a difference of two squares, as is $ \ x^2 - 36 \ $, so

$$(x^4 - 1296) \ = \ [ \ (x^2)^2 \ - \ (36^2) \ ] \ = \ (x^2 + 36) \ \cdot (x^2 - 36 ) $$

$$= \ (x^2 + 36) \cdot (x - 6) \cdot (x + 6) \ = \ (x^3 \ + \ 36x \ - \ 6x^2 - 216 ) \cdot (x + 6) \ . $$

EDIT: I missed that **Πάρτη Κοηλί** had done this going down to complex roots; this version "keeps things real"...

All of the answers I see at the present are fine -- there isn't any getting around that one needs to recognize that 1296 is $ \ 6^4 \ $ , or otherwise needs to find enough factors of 1296 to see a way to "break down" the polynomial.

Comment: I agree. :-) ${}$

Comment: Thank you for your response. It really helps! I just accepted julien responses because it is generic.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{r|rrrr|r}
& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1296 \\
-6 & & -6 & 36 & -216 & 1296 \\
\hline
& 1 & -6 & 36 & -216 & 0
\end{array}
$$

This shows that
$$
x^4-1296=(x+6)(x^3-6x^2+36x-216)
$$

Of course you can also use

$$
a^4 - b^4 = (a-b)(a^3 + a^2b + ab^2 + b^3)
$$
with $a=x$ and $b=-6$.

Comment: $a^4 - b^4 = (a - b)(a^3 + a^2 b + ab^2 + b^3)$...

Comment: @ΠάρτηΚοηλί The first method doesn't need to remember that decomposition; of course the computations are exactly the same.

Comment: Uh, actually I am saying that you wrote $a^4 - b^4 = a^3 + a^2 b + ab^2 + b^3$. It should be $a^4 - b^4 = (a - b)(a^3 + a^2 b + ab^2 + b^3)$

Comment: @ΠάρτηΚοηλί Oh! Thanks! I couldn't see it.

Comment: @egreg, what is the name of the method used in the table? You comment in the question "dividing", but which is the specifically name of it? Thank you.

Comment: @Lourenco That's called "Horner scheme" or, in Italy, *metodo di Ruffini*. It's just an abbreviated form of long division.

Comment: (Mostly known as the synthetic division.)

Comment: Very good to know about [synthetic division](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/polynomials/dividing_polynomials/v/synthetic-division).

Comment: Thank you for your response. It really helps! I just accepted julien responses because it is generic.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic result of field theory that if a binomial $\, x^n - c\,$ is reducible then it has a proper factor given by the Factor Theorem or difference of squares, of one of the following two forms

$$\begin{eqnarray} \text{Factor Theorem}\!:\ \ & x^n - a^n &=\,& (x\ -\ a)\,(\cdots) \\ \Rightarrow\ \ {\rm Form_1}\!:\ \ &(x^k)^p\!-a^p &=\,& (x^k- a)\, (\cdots)\quad \text{for prime}\ \  p\mid n \\
\Rightarrow\ \ {\rm Form_2}\!:\ \  & x^{4k}\! + 4a^4 &=\,& (x^{2k}\!+2a^2)^2 - (2ax^k)^2 = \ \cdots \end{eqnarray}$$

So $\, x^4\! - 1296\,$ reducible $\,\Rightarrow\, 1296 = a^2,\,a^4,\,{\rm or}\,\ {-}4a^4.\,$ $\,1296 = 4\cdot 324 = 4\cdot 4\cdot 81 = 2^4\cdot 3^4,\,$ hence we obtain factors of Form$_1,\,$ viz. $\, x^4-(\pm a)^4 =  (x\mp a)\,(\cdots)$

A proof of said theorem can be found in Karpilovsky, [Topics in Field Theory, Theorem 8.1.6.](http://books.google.com/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425)